# How to display images foreach report of Rmarkdown through a loop?

Tags: r, r-markdown

i'm trying to aumatize PDF reports through Rmarkdown. Until now i manage to insert covers, header and footer inside the loop, but now i'm trying to introduce images inside of each report. The idea is that every class (100, 200, 300) has his own corresponding image, so i have 3 images (100.jpg, 200.jpg, 300.jpg) to insert; the "100.jpg" inside the first report, the "200.jpg" inside the second report and so on. I left the looping code and the Rmd i'm using right now:

Script:

```
  class_list <- list(
    list(prof = "Colegio 1", class = "100"),
    list(prof = "Colegio 2", class = "200"),
    list(prof = "Colegio 3", class = "300")
  )
  
  purrr::walk(class_list, function(class_info) {
    prof <- class_info$prof
    class <- class_info$class
    rmarkdown::render(
      input = "C:/Users/seare/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/4.0/pdfreport/example/Untitled/Informes_MueveTP.Rmd", 
      output_file = sprintf("C:/Users/seare/downloads/Report_output_%s.pdf", prof, class),
      params = list(prof = prof, class = class)
    )
  })
```

Rmd

````
---
title: "`r params$prof`"
author: "RBD `r params$class`"
date: 10-10-2022
params:
  prof: "Colegios de Media"
  class: "RBD de la Escuela"
  logo: logo.jpg
  cover: background.jpg
  iblue: 2b4894
  igray: d4dbde
documentclass: article
fontsize: 10
papersize: a4paper
output: 
  IReports::businessReport:
    keep_tex: TRUE
    latex_engine: xelatex
    resetStyleFiles: FALSE
header-includes: 
  - \newcommand{\logo}{`r gsub("_", "\\_", params$logo)`}
  - \newcommand{\cover}{`r gsub("_", "\\_", params$cover)`}
  - \newcommand{\iblue}{`r params$iblue`}
  - \newcommand{\igray}{`r params$igray`}
include-before:
  - \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
  - \renewcommand{\pagename}{Seite}
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
# packages
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

# settings
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)

# Graph
knitr::include_graphics("C:/Users/seare/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/4.0/pdfreport/example/Untitled/RBD_.jpg")
```
````

The idea i was thinking is to generate the image loop in the last lines of the code chunk (# Graph), but i don't know if it is better to do it in the script.

Thanks everyone:)